# Upgrade from disco to eaon - 4 packages can be upgraded, but not possible to update

Tags: upgrade, 19.04

Im trying to upgrade to 19.10 from my 19.04 which is EOL.

```
# apt update
4 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
```

```
apt list --upgradable
libgl1-mesa-dri/bionic-security 19.2.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.2 amd64 [upgradable from: 19.0.8-0ubuntu0~19.04.1]
libgl1-mesa-dri/bionic-security 19.2.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.2 i386 [upgradable from: 19.0.8-0ubuntu0~19.04.1]
libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18/bionic-security 2.26.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.26.2-0ubuntu0.19.04.1]
libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37/bionic-security 2.26.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.26.2-0ubuntu0.19.04.1]
```

```
apt -f upgrade
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

```
apt dist-upgrade
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

```
apt install libgl1-mesa-dri
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgl1-mesa-dri : Depends: libsensors4 (>= 1:3.0.0) but it is not installable
                   Breaks: libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 (!= 19.2.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.2) but 19.0.8-0ubuntu0~19.04.1 is to be installed
 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 : Breaks: libgl1-mesa-dri (!= 19.0.8-0ubuntu0~19.04.1) but 19.2.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.2 is to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

So how do I then do the `sudo do-release-upgrade` as this is complaining about I need to install updates

Comment: Why do you have bionic repos when neither your old or new version is bionic?

Comment: Thanks @OrganicMarble - I found a bionic deb file in my sources list, and when removed everything works. Apparently eyes is the first you get blind on :)

Comment: glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you are trying to upgrade to 19.10 (`eoan`) from 19.04 (`disco`), your sources contain some 18.04 (`bionic`) entries. Use the following command to find them:

```
grep -r bionic /etc/apt/sources.list*
```

Then use your favorite text editor to edit the found files and remove or upgrade the `bionic` entries manually.

See also: [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories)